# Ajax working with XAMPP but not with Apache2 server

Tags: php, ajax, apache

I have this very simple project making use of Ajax:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id='btn'>Click</button>
        <script src='jquery-3.6.3.min.js'></script>
        <script src='main.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
$('#btn').click(() => {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: res => {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(res);
        },
        error: errorThrown => {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    })
})
```

and php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);

    $url='http://api.geonames.org/geoCodeAddressJSON?formatted=true&q=Madrid&username=my_user_name&style=full';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $decode = json_decode($result,true);    

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
    $output['data'] = $decode['address'];

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

I have installed Apache2 following that [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-20-04) with the project in `/var/www/html/my_project` and I have also installed XAMPP following that [tutorial](https://vitux.com/ubuntu-xampp/) with the very same project in /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_project.

When using XAMPP:

`sudo service apache2 stop`
`sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`
and in my browser: `localhost/my_project`,
the Ajax call works fine.

But when using Apache2:
`sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop`
`sudo service apache2 start`
and in the browser: `localhost/my_project`,

the Ajax doesn't work and throw the following:

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://localhost/test/test.php
Line Number 29, Column 1:
```

as well as:

```
Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(e), getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(e, t), overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(e), statusCode: statusCode(e), abort: abort(e), state: state(), always: always(), catch: catch(e)
, … }
​
abort: function abort(e)​
always: function always()​
catch: function catch(e)​
done: function add()​
fail: function add()​
getAllResponseHeaders: function getAllResponseHeaders()​
getResponseHeader: function getResponseHeader(e)​
overrideMimeType: function overrideMimeType(e)​
pipe: function pipe()​
progress: function add()​
promise: function promise(e)
​
readyState: 4
​
responseText: `<?php\nini_set('display_errors', 'On');\n    error_reporting(E_ALL);\n\n    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);\n\n    $url='http://api.geonames.org/geoCodeAddressJSON?formatted=true&q=Paris,France&username=clovis&style=full';\n    $ch = curl_init();\n    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);\n    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);\n    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);\n\n    $result=curl_exec($ch);\n\n    curl_close($ch);\n\n    $decode = json_decode($result,true);\t\n\n    $output['status']['code'] = "200";\n    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";\n    $output['status']['description'] = "success";\n    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";\n    $output['data'] = $decode['address'];\n\n    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');\n\n    echo json_encode($output);\n?>\n`
​
setRequestHeader: function setRequestHeader(e, t)​
state: function state()
​
status: 200
​
statusCode: function statusCode(e)
​
statusText: "OK"
​
then: function then(t, n, r)​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

In both locations, the file permissions are the same. I'd like to understand the issue here.

Comment: You know xampp already comes with apache? It's not clear why you installed independent Apache and then also xampp

Comment: I just wanted to try both, but I've found the solution anyway: I needed to install `libapache2-mod-php8.1` and `php8.1-curl`.